# find document in mongo by a pecif field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have he following schema in mongodb:

[image]

I am trying to get all documents by a certain organization as set in the regex, but I do not get the proper filtered list.

I have also tried
geopoints.find(organization:"abc123"). Not sure why I am not getting a filtered list.

```
const promise2 = geopoints.find({organization: {$regex: 'abc123'}}, {locations:1, organization:1, _id:0})
```

Here is the full code:

```
app.get('/onlyfields', (req, res) => {
    //onlyfields.find()
    //.then(data => res.send({fields: data, rows: [[2, '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00', '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00', 1, 1.64, -73.9837265, 40.74634171, -73.96679688, 40.76140594, 8.5, 0, 9.3], [2, '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00', '2015-01-15 14:19:26 +00:00', 1, 1.53, -73.99578094, 40.73294067, -73.99107361, 40.75038147, 12, 0, 12.8]]}))
 
      //FIND ALL CONSULTATIONS FILTERED BY STATUS
      const promise1 = onlyfields.find({}, {_id:0})
      const promise2 = geopoints.find({organization: 'abc123'}, {locations:1, organization:1, _id:0})
      
      Promise.all([promise1, promise2]) 
        .then(([result1, result2]) => {
     
          const flatData = result2.map(currEntry => currEntry.locations)
          res.send({ fields: result1, rows: flatData })
          //console.log(flatData)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'Erorr en STATUS2'
          })
        })
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `toArray()` to convert cursor to an `Array promise`

```
find().toArray()
```

Comment: Tried it, no change, still getting all the records.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Gives an error: 

geopoints.find(...).toArray is not a function

Comment: Where do you import or obtain `geopoints`?

Comment: They are in the collection I have mentioned in the OP. The locations array contains the data for each geopoint. I am able to get the whole document when I run the above code, only the filter does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to dump your geopoints, without filter, to see what is actually getting returned?